# Show that $1$ is the only root and that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 1$ and that $f(x) < 0$ at $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $ f(x) = 2x^{3} - \sqrt{x^2 +3x}$

I want to show that $1$ is the only root and that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 1$ and that $f(x) < 0$ at $(0,1)$

**CANNOT USE DERIVATIVE CONCEPT, JUST LIMIT**

Well, first I noticed that the function is continuous on $[0, \infty]$, since it's the subtraction of continuous functions.

Then, without using any theorem, by substitution, I realized that $f(1) = 0$, $f\left(\frac12\right) < 0$ and that $f(2) > 0$. Then I considered that there is $c > 0$ in $(0, \infty)$ such that $f(c) = 0$, so

$$
4c^{5} - c -3 = 0
$$

So, I noticed that only $c=1$ satisfies the equation. But is there a way using Limit and Continuity Theorem (Intermediate Value Theorem, nulling for example)?

To show that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 1$, I thought of the intermediate value theorem, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Why is $x=0$ not a root ?

Comment: @lonestudent in $(0, +\infty)$.

Comment: Are you only interested in $x>0$? If so you need to say so explicitly since $0$ is also a zero of $f(x).$

Comment: @Allawonder OK. But that's obvious.

Comment: The term obvious is not a well-defined term, especially not here since your question does not imply the domain you're interested in, in any logical sense of the term. What's more, the claim is fasle as stated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x>1$, then
$$
x ^2+3x<x^6+3x^6=4x^6.
$$
As the square root is monotone and all arguments are positive,
$$
\sqrt{x^2+3x}<2x^3.
$$
When $0<x<1$,
$$
x ^2+3x>x^6+3x^6=4x^6.
$$
As the square root is monotone and all arguments are positive,
$$
\sqrt{x^2+3x}>2x^3.
$$

Comment: Is there any way using theorems like: Intermediate Value or Nullification Theorem or another theorem?

Comment: You want the argument to be **less** direct?

Comment: It's just that the goal would be to use arguments citing theorems like the one I cited earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Usually you would use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that some concrete value is achieved (like from $f(1/2)<0$ and $f(2)>0$ you can deduce that there is a root in between); but I don't see how to use it here. I have no idea what the Nullification Theorem is.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\;$ write it as $\,f(x) = \dfrac{4x^6 - x^2 - 3 x}{2x^{3} + \sqrt{x^2 +3x}} = \dfrac{x (x - 1) (4 x^4 + 4 x^3 + 4 x^2 + 4 x + 3)}{2x^{3} + \sqrt{x^2 +3x}}\,$.

Comment: I could not understand. Where am I going to use this stand? where did this fraction come from? What am I going to use this tip for?

Comment: @Narutochin $f(x)=\big(2x^{3} - \sqrt{x^2 +3x}\big)\cdot \frac{2x^{3} + \sqrt{x^2 +3x}}{2x^{3} + \sqrt{x^2 +3x}} = \frac{(2x^3)^2 - (\sqrt{x^2 +3x})^2}{2x^{3} + \sqrt{x^2 +3x}}$.

Comment: And how do you know that $x=1$ and $x=0$ are the only roots of that equation there? That polynomial of degree 4.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @Narutochin For $x \gt 0$ all the factors in the last expression are strictly positive, except possibly $(x-1)$. It doesn't matter that it's a $4^{th}$ degree polynomial, but each term $x^k \gt 0$ so $4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+3$ $\gt 0+0+0+0+3=3$. It follows that the sign and the roots of $f(x)$ are the same as the sign and the roots of $(x-1)$ on $\mathbb R^+$.

Answer (score 4):

Finding the zero of $ \ f(x) \ $ can also be regarded as determining the intersection of the curves for $ \ g(x) \ = \ 2x^{3} \ $ and $ \ h(x) \ = \   \sqrt{x^2 +3x} \ \ . \ $  The curve for $ \ h(x) \ $ is the "half" on or "above" the $ \ x-$axis of the "horizontal" hyperbola $ \ y^2 \ - \ \left(x + \frac32 \right)^2 \ = \ \frac94 \ \ , \ $ which has the asymptotes $ \ y \ = \ \pm \left( x + \frac32 \right) \ \ . $

It is plain that there can be no intersections of the curves for $ \ x \ < \ 0 \ \ , \ $ and there are intersections at the origin and at $ \ ( 1 \ , \ 2 ) \ . \ $  In the interval $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ 1 \ \ , \ $  we find that
$$ x^2 \ < \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x·(x^2 - 1) \ < \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ g(x) \ = \ 2x^3 \ < \ 2x \ \ , $$
whereas
$$ 3x^2 \ < \ 3x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 4x^2 \ < \ 3x + x^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x \ < \ h(x) \ = \ \sqrt{x^2 + 3x} \ \ , \ $$

or we may use **Martin Argerami**'s arguments.  Applying this to the problem statement, we thus have $ \ f(x) \ = \ g(x) - h(x) \ < \ 0 \ \ . \ $

For $ \ x \ > \ 1 \ \ , \ $ both functions "grow to positive infinity", but $ \ g(x) \ $ does so as a cubic function, while we see that $ \ h(x) \ $ is bounded above by the *linear* function $  \ y \ = \ x + \frac32 \ \ . $  So $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ $ is the only positive root of the original equation and $ \ f(x) \  > \ 0 \ \  $ for $ \ x \ > \ 1 \ \ . $